# Bootstrap collapsible grid that changes adjusts for screen size

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I am trying to make a collapsible grid on bootstrap to show details of each item:

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lCdkx.png) is a link to a picture to show the main idea. 
I have been following the following thread which has been very useful: https://www.codeply.com/go/TLJi5MxQ1E

However they way that their html is coded, each row on small screen must be a factor of each row on a large screen (eg. 4 rows on screen --> 2 rows on a small screen)

What I am trying to do is to have 3 increments: 3 columns, 2 columns, and 1 column and I am unable to figure out how to make it work. Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

a few things:

You should add what you have tried to accomplish this instead of just coming here for someone to write code for you.

With that said, I used to do the same thing occasionally in my earlier questions, so i have decided to help you.

here is the solution for desktop (without bootstrap) keep in mind bootstrap is dynamic and will adjust your content to screen size on tablet, desktop or mobile.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <style>
            #container {
                display: flex;
                flex-direction: column;
                border: 2px solid grey;
            }

            .row {
                display: flex;
                align-content: center;
                justify-content: center;
            }

            img {
                height: 200px;
                width: 200px;
                border: 1px solid black;
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="container">
            <div class="row">
                <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/proxy/fEYdsyPpuHjBaYcf-ImCa4jrGrKo3qIHzfgEvoYHMPQaqrxuPXHzDFxhL15qpYPOYp-8R0ELgc0JZ0LCJaLgDghVBu3a_TTAOB2cPu5tdt_Kb03WFEflMWse2H9KGPJ1aMRCoARvdofMWBFnVhavJw">
                <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/proxy/fEYdsyPpuHjBaYcf-ImCa4jrGrKo3qIHzfgEvoYHMPQaqrxuPXHzDFxhL15qpYPOYp-8R0ELgc0JZ0LCJaLgDghVBu3a_TTAOB2cPu5tdt_Kb03WFEflMWse2H9KGPJ1aMRCoARvdofMWBFnVhavJw">
                <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/proxy/fEYdsyPpuHjBaYcf-ImCa4jrGrKo3qIHzfgEvoYHMPQaqrxuPXHzDFxhL15qpYPOYp-8R0ELgc0JZ0LCJaLgDghVBu3a_TTAOB2cPu5tdt_Kb03WFEflMWse2H9KGPJ1aMRCoARvdofMWBFnVhavJw">
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/proxy/fEYdsyPpuHjBaYcf-ImCa4jrGrKo3qIHzfgEvoYHMPQaqrxuPXHzDFxhL15qpYPOYp-8R0ELgc0JZ0LCJaLgDghVBu3a_TTAOB2cPu5tdt_Kb03WFEflMWse2H9KGPJ1aMRCoARvdofMWBFnVhavJw">
                <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/proxy/fEYdsyPpuHjBaYcf-ImCa4jrGrKo3qIHzfgEvoYHMPQaqrxuPXHzDFxhL15qpYPOYp-8R0ELgc0JZ0LCJaLgDghVBu3a_TTAOB2cPu5tdt_Kb03WFEflMWse2H9KGPJ1aMRCoARvdofMWBFnVhavJw">
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/proxy/fEYdsyPpuHjBaYcf-ImCa4jrGrKo3qIHzfgEvoYHMPQaqrxuPXHzDFxhL15qpYPOYp-8R0ELgc0JZ0LCJaLgDghVBu3a_TTAOB2cPu5tdt_Kb03WFEflMWse2H9KGPJ1aMRCoARvdofMWBFnVhavJw">
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>

</html>
```

if you want to customize this further, you will need to familiarize yourself with media queries in CSS. you can write rules for displaying 2 per row, or 4 per row, or whatever per row, based on your own logic.

with the code here and some research on media queries, you will be able to accomplish this.

IF...you update your question with some code, and what you have tried (i have given you code and pointed you in the right direction) I will be happy to comment or help.

Cheers